# Después de un cout por alguna razón se imprime tambien un cero

Tags: c++

En el cout de la linea numero 10 despues de imprimir aparece un cero sin razon alguna, es esto algun tipo de bug? o es que hice algo mal?
[image: Compilacion del codigo]

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int conteo = 0;
int limite;
    cout<<"Hasta que numero desea contar?: ";
    cin>>limite;
cout<<"Numeros del 1 al "<<limite;
    while(conteo <= limite){
        cout<<conteo++<<"\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int conteo = 0;
    int limite;

    cout << "¿Hasta qué número desea contar?: ";
    cin >> limite;
    cout << "Números del 1 al " << limite;

    while (conteo <= limite) {
        // cout << conteo++ << "\n"; // Pos-incremento
        cout << ++conteo << "\n"; // Pre-incremento
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

en tu código, estás usando el operador de posincremento en `conteo`. En la primera iteración del bucle, el valor será cero y en la segunda iteración se le añadirá 1.

El operador de posincremento, `++`, se coloca después de la variable:

```
conteo++
```

Si cambias a preincremento, el valor inicial será 1. En la primera iteración, se incrementará a 2, en la segunda a 3 y así sucesivamente.

El preincremento, `++`, se coloca antes de la variable:

```
++conteo
```

En el preincremento, se agrega un valor a la variable y luego se actualiza.
En el incremento posterior, primero se actualiza el valor y luego se incrementa un nuevo valor.

codigo de ejemplo [**replit**](https://replit.com/@cardosource/Solucion-esstackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

El 0 aparece cuando imprimes la variable `conteo`.

Lo notarás mejor si agregas un salto de línea luego del mensaje:

```
cout << "Numeros del 1 al " << limite << '\n';
```

La solución más simple es iniciar `conteo` en 1.

---

Tanto el operador de pre-incremento como el post-incremento incrementan la variable.

La diferencia está en el resultado de la expresión.

El operador de pre-incremento resulta en el valor actual de la variable.

```
int a = 10;
int b = ++a;
// a = b = 11
```

Mientras que e post-incremento resulta en el valor anterior de la variable.

```
int a = 10;
int b = a++;
// a = 11
// b = 10
```

Por lo tanto tu código es equivalente a este:

```
while(conteo <= limite){
    int anterior = conteo;
    cout << conteo << '\n';
    conteo += 1;
}
```

Eso explica que el primer valor impreso sea el 0 y el último el 10. Teniendo en cuenta que la variable `conteo` se inicia en 0 y utilizas el operador post-incremento.

---

Si te ayuda, puedes pensar los operadores como funciones que se verían así:

```
// Los parámetros son referencias a las variables.
// Por lo tanto, al modificar `n` en realidad se modifica la variable original.

int pre_incremento(int &n){
    n += 1;
    return n;
}

int post_incremento(int &n){
    int valor_anterior = n;
    n += 1;
    return valor_anterior;
}
```